# Print BTree by level

Tags: java, applet, b-tree

I am trying to create a Java applet that animates a BTree.  I have code to create the tree but now I am trying to display it.  I thought the easiest way would be to print by level but I can't figure out how.  The below code is the constructor for my nodes.  Also, if anyone has a better suggestion for displaying my tree I would appreciate it.

```
    /***********************************************************************
 * Class BTNode
 * The BTNode is nothing else than a Node in the BTree. This nodes can be
 * greater or smaller it depends on the users order.
 **/

class BTNode {
    int order=0;
    int nKey=0;         // number of keys stored in node
    KeyNode kArray[];       // array where keys are stored
    BTNode btnArray[];  // array where references to the next BTNodes is stored
    boolean isLeaf;     // is the btnode a leaf
    BTNode parent;      // link to the parent node

    /**
       * BTNode(int order, BTNode parent);
       * Constructor, creats a empty node with the given order and parent
       **/
    BTNode(int order, BTNode parent) {
        this.order = order;
        this.parent = parent;
        kArray = new KeyNode[2 * order - 1];
        btnArray = new BTNode[2 * order];
        isLeaf = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to perform a level-order traversal of the tree.  If space is not a limiting factor, I'd suggest building a queue of nodes that you wish to visit next (adding their child nodes onto the end of the queue upon visit).

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I ended up using two queues (adding all the children of the nodes in the first queue to the second queue and then vice versa) this way I could keep track of when a line break was needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend a level order transversal. Here  is some sudocode for it:

```
Add root to queue
while queue is not empty
{
    r = queue.top()
    process r
    remove r from queue
    add r's non-NULL children to the queue
}
```